# Second website on another domain's folder

Tags: websites, folder

Is this possible:

Main Website A:
www.domain.com

Website B:
www.second-domain.com/sitefolder

We need a second website to work on different domain's sub folder. Both sites are on the same server. I know it's possible to use another domain for second website, but is the folder doable?

Comment: You can update the url rows in `core_config_data` (within the second domain's db) to include the folder, just make sure you include the trailing slash www.second-domain.com/sitefolder/

Comment: Second domain's database? I mean to use one Magento installation and currently we have the second website (within the same magento installation) on sub folder of the same domain. Now we need to transfer that second website to another domain's subfolder and I need to know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

1- In the sitefolder folder create symbolic link for APP, MEDIA, JS

3- copy index.php and htacces to sitefolder

2- in Magento backend under the new store scope add the new domain name

3- in the new site index.php do this Mage::run('newstore','website');